problem with displaying cadquery objects in jupyter notebook (cannot retrieve Open CASCADE version)
I am trying to get a minimum working example of jupyter-cadquery to run on my Windows PC:
import cadquery as cq

from jupyter_cadquery import (
    versions,
    show, PartGroup, Part,
    get_viewer, close_viewer, get_viewers, close_viewers, open_viewer, set_defaults, get_defaults, open_viewer,
    get_pick,
)

from jupyter_cadquery.replay import replay, enable_replay, disable_replay
''
enable_replay(False)

set_defaults(
    cad_width=640,
    height=480,
)

versions()
box = cq.Workplane('XY').box(1, 2, 3).edges().fillet(0.1)
cv = open_viewer("CadQuery", anchor="right")  # sets default viewer
show(box, viewer=None, up="Y")

When opening the ipynb-file in the jupyter notebook and running the cells, I get the following error:
Versions:
- jupyter_cadquery  3.5.2
- cad_viewer_widget 1.4.1
- open cascade      (cannot retrieve Open CASCADE version)

ERROR displaying widget

I downloaded the OCC binaries, but I do not know where put them.
Kind regards
Bastian
